# Producing a nearest neighbour distance map for a set of points

Tags: python, nearest-neighbor

I have a list of (x,y) points.  I'm trying to produce a plot of the distance to each point as an image, so my naive function looks like:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from numpy import *

def findDistances(imageSize, points):
    image = zeros(imageSize)
    for x in range(0,imageSize[1]):
        for y in range(0,imageSize[0]):
            image[y,x] = np.min(cdist(array([[x,y]]), points))
    return image
```

This function is fine, it gives what I want (see picture below).  This takes about 100s for a ~1MP image which is fine for something that only ever needs to be done once, but I assume there's room for improvement.  I also tried:

```
image[y,x] = min(linalg.norm(array([[x,y]])- points, axis=1))
```

Which runs in a comparable time - makes sense, they're probably doing something similar under the hood, though I haven't checked the source to be sure.

I had a look at Scipy's cKDTree, with:

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

def findDistancesTree(imageSize, points):
    tree = cKDTree(points)
    image = zeros(imageSize)
    for x in range(0,imageSize[1]):
        for y in range(0,imageSize[0]):
            image[y,x] = tree.query([x,y])[0]
    return image
```

A call to `tree.query` takes around 50µs (from `%timeit`) and in reality it takes 70-80s to generate a 1MP distance map.  20s improvement is better than a kick in the groin, but I don't know if I can improve it further.

```
%timeit np.min(linalg.norm(array([[random.random()*1000,random.random()*1000]]) - points, axis=1))
%timeit np.min(cdist(array([[random.random()*1000,random.random()*1000]]), points))
%timeit tree.query(array([[random.random()*1000,random.random()*1000]]))

10000 loops, best of 3: 82.8 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 67.9 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 52.3 µs per loop
```

In terms of complexity, brute force should be something like `O(NM)` where `N` is the number of pixels in the image and `M` is the number of points to check against.  I was expecting more of a speedup as the search time should be more like `O(N log(M))` for `N` pixels with a `log(M)` look-up time for each one - am I missing something?

[image: Imgur]

Comment: I think the basic kd tree's nearest neighbor search is not usually a O(log(M)) operation since your points are not randomly distributed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounded like a problem where even a basic brute force implementation with a GPU would give good improvement. So i gave it a shot. And the improvement was quite good.

I did my testing using pyopencl.

```
import pyopencl as cl 
import numpy as np 

def findDistances_cl(imageSize, points):
    #Boilerplate opencl code
    ctx = cl.create_some_context()
    queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

    f = open('nn.cl', 'r')
    fstr = "".join(f.readlines())
    program = cl.Program(ctx, fstr).build()

    #Creating buffers for the opencl kernel
    mf = cl.mem_flags
    img = np.empty(imageSize, dtype=np.float32)
    x_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.USE_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=points[:,0].astype(np.float32))
    y_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.USE_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=points[:,1].astype(np.float32))
    n_points = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.USE_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=np.array([len(points)],dtype=np.int))
    img_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, img.nbytes)

    #Run the kernel
    exec_evt = program.nn(queue, img.shape, None, img_buf, x_buf, y_buf, n_points)
    exec_evt.wait()
    #read back the result
    cl.enqueue_read_buffer(queue, img_buf, img).wait()

    return img
```

the opencl kernel (nn.cl)

```
__kernel void nn(__global float *output, __global constant float *x , __global constant float *y, __global constant int *numPoints)
    {
        int row = get_global_id(0);
        int col = get_global_id(1);

        int numRows = get_global_size(0);
        int numCols = get_global_size(1);

        int gid = col+ row*numCols;

        float minDist = numRows * numCols;

        for(int i = 0; i < *numPoints; i++){
          minDist = min(minDist, sqrt((row - y[i])*(row - y[i]) + (col - x[i])*(col - x[i])));
        }
        output[gid] = minDist;
    }
```

Timing results.

```
imageSize = [1000, 1000]
points = np.random.random((1000,2))*imageSize[0]

In [4]: %timeit findDistancesTree(imageSize, points)
1 loops, best of 3: 27.1 s per loop

In [7]: %timeit findDistances_cl(imageSize, points)
10 loops, best of 3: 55.3 ms per loop
```

About 490x speed improvement. If you need more speed there are more advanced algorithms out there for doing nearest neighbors with GPUs.

Comment: That's pretty awesome, it takes about 2.5 seconds on my GeForce 9400M.  I'll give it a go on my iMac, think it's got something beefier.  Never played with pyopencl before, seems pretty straightforward to use!  I also edited to include __globals in the function definition, it hung my system otherwise - I checked the output and it looks good with the change.

Comment: @Josh i edited in your suggested edit, seems like your edit got rejected by the reviwers. Altough i seem to remember there is some other flag for the parameters that would make them be placed in local memory for each kernel. That might be faster. http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/local.html

Comment: Any idea why it hung before?  The module compiled OK, runs, but the call to `wait()` never returned.

Comment: Also an update on the edit - it's possibly dependent on the version of OpenCL.  On my iMac, your original code compiles without any issues (and runs in 0.31 seconds on a Radeon 6770M).  So possibly just my clunky old Macbook causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Voronoi diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) and [Fortune's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune%27s_algorithm) lead to the solution you want.

The idea would be:

- compute the Voronoi diagram or your M points in O(M ln(M))
- for each of the N pixels

  - find the corresponding region
  - compute the distance to the point of the region

The question is now how to find the region corresponding to a pixel in O(ln(M)).

Hope this helps !

Comment: It did occur to me.  I tried using Scipy's voronoi functions and matplotlib's paths.

Checking each polygon for a hit took about 10µs.  Problem is there's 1200 or so polygons and checking each one amounts to the same thing as a brute force, I guess there's a smarter way again to decide which polygons to check.

The actual diagram generation is very quick, only a few msecs.

Comment: I guess there's a smarter way too. "Point-location" query is well documented in [CGAL documentation](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/index.html#title13). It could be a great source of inspiration.

Comment: Point-location is very difficult to understand. Better not.

Comment: Difficult but efficient. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hierarchical cluster to cluster the points,I.e dendogram. For each tree  you can compute the voronoi diagram and a point-in-polygone function.